# Periodic boundary conditions: torus or infinite images?

Tags: simulations, boundary-conditions, interactions, molecular-dynamics

I have a "philosophical" question regarding the use of periodic boundary conditions (PBD) in modeling and simulating systems of particles.

Let us consider a system of $N$ classical particles whose dynamics is described by Hamilton equations with the following Hamiltonian:
$$
H(\boldsymbol{x}_1,...,\boldsymbol{x}_N,\boldsymbol{p}_1,...,\boldsymbol{p}_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\boldsymbol{p}_i}{2m_i} + U(\boldsymbol{x}_1,...,\boldsymbol{x}_N) \; ,
$$
where $U$ is a generic interaction potential.

Usually, in methods like Molecular Dynamics (MD) the motion of particles is obtained via numerical integration of said Hamilton equations in a box with PBC using the *minimum-image convention* (MIC), that is defining the distance between two particles as the minimum distance between all the periodic images of said particles.

PBC + MIC have quite some important implications, as they affect the metric of the space in which the particles move. On a 'practical' standpoint, it is usually said that due to PCB + MIC it is not possible to cut-off long-range interactions (e.g Coulomb electrostatics, Newtonian gravity, etc...) due to the fact that the sum of said interactions over infinite periodic images is only conditionally convergent. This is why Ewald summation is needed to compute electrostatics in MD, for example.

Now, my question is: are there really infinite images? PBC can be either interpreted as "the systems moves on a torus" or "the system is replicated infinitely in a Cartesian space". Does using a special treatment of long-range interactions that assumes infinite periodic images single-out the latter interpretation and discard the former?

If the system moves on a torus, there's no need to compute the interactions over infinite images since all the images are the same image and there are *truly* only $N$ particles, so one can just directly sum over them. Or maybe the way I am approaching this question is completely wrong.

**EDIT I**: I thought I could also mention the reason why I am asking this question. In the famous book by Frenkel and Smith on molecular simulations [1] PBC are introduced to address the following problem:

> In order to simulate bulk phases it is essential to choose boundary
> conditions that mimic the presence of an infinite bulk surrounding the
> N-particle model system

To me, an *infinite bulk* and a *torus* are conceptually very different! On a more practical note, I think the *infinite bulk* interpretation of PBC is suitable for material science, while the *torus* one is more suitable for biophysics.

[1] Daan Frenkel and Berend Smit, *Understanding Molecular Simulation: From Algorithms to Applications*, Academic Press 2002

**EDIT II**: After reading the answers I got so far, I think that what I should really be asking myself is why "long-range interactions wrap more around the torus" (quoting @Quillo). But that is probably a separate question.

Comment: In case you do not get an answer here, consider to ask this question on Matter Modeling SE; however, note the rules regarding cross-posting.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761819/thermodynamic-limit-and-periodic-boundary-conditions) question and also a nice answer by @LPZ.

Comment: Regarding the edit: PBC= "flat torus". A rectangle with PBC is exactly a flat torus (I.e. it has the torus topology but not the curvature of the usual toroidal surface). A flat torus is a finite size system, so it is not the same as the infinite bulk, but if the torus is large enough then you can claim that you're simulating the system in its thermodynamic limit (both the torus and the infinite space are manifolds without boundaries and invariant under translations).

Comment: @Quillo well, in molecular simulations you are almost always very far from the thermodynamic limit. If the flat torus is a finite dimensional system, why does one need special treatment for long-range interactions? Can't I just sum over the finite amount of particle pairs in the system, instead of all infinite periodic images?

Comment: There is a method, called finite-size scaling, that allows validating if the computational domain (i.e. the flat torus) is large enough that the results do not depend on its size. This is how you practically achieve the thermodynamic limit in MD. Yes, long-range interactions make everything more difficult but it is often seen numerically that the strategy still works most of the time. Long-range interactions "wrap" more around the torus, so you need to numerically sum this infinite series. (check the Poisson summation formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)

Comment: @Quillo thank you. Let's focus on the topology rather than the thermodynamics limit (I think they are two separate issues).
I believe that the key point here is that do long-range interactions wrap more (infinitely more?) around the torus. If that's the case, my original question is ill-posed. But I still cannot fully understand why this happens, i.e. why one would need to compute infinite pair interactions in a system than only has a finite amount of particles.

Comment: @uhoh the point is: I already know the 'how'. I don't know the 'why'.

Comment: @MichelePellegrino ya I see now. Hmm... Then consider [Physics Overflow](https://physicsoverflow.org/)?  This site is hit-or-miss; sometimes great answers, but sometimes nothing but crickets...

Comment: @MichelePellegrino you have to consider infinite pairs of interactions because you have infinite pairs: the torus is equivalent to a periodic lattice on the plane. Even if you consider the torus as a finite system, the interaction wraps initite times around it (it does not go to zero at infinity because there is no infinity on the torus). The same is valid for any compact manifold.

Comment: @Quillo "it does not go to zero at infinity because there is no infinity on the torus". I think I get it now. It's not really about the pairs (ane whether one has a finite or infinite number of them): it's about the interaction potential, and ultimately how to approximate an aperiodic function in a infinite Cartesian space with a periodic function on a torus. I think this goes much deeper than any explanation I have found on MD textbooks so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PBC means that the system moves on a torus. This means that the particle positions $x$ are thought of as being defined up to a lattice $\Lambda$, i.e. living in $\mathbb R^D/\Lambda$. The issue is that your interaction term $U$ is therefore multivalued in this context, or in other words it is not $\Lambda$ periodic. You therefore need to periodise it to $U_\Lambda$, i.e. you want it to satisfy for all $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N\in\Lambda$ and all $x_1,...,x_N\in\mathbb R^D$:
$$
U_\Lambda(x_1,...,x_N) = U_\Lambda(x_1+\lambda_1,...,x_N+\lambda_N)
$$
As a consistency condition, as the spatial periodicity goes to infinity, you should recover the original potential, so:
$$
U_{L\Lambda} \xrightarrow{L\to\infty} U
$$

There are many ways to do this. One way is to use your infinite images:
$$
U_\Lambda(x_1,...,x_N) = \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda^N}U(x_1+\lambda_1,...,x_N+\lambda_N)
$$
It's a nice method if $U$ decays fast enough. In Fourier space, it is equivalent to sampling the Fourier transform on the dual lattice $\Lambda^*$. It also preserves smoothness etc. However when $U$ does not decay fast enough, you need to define the summation carefully.

The MIC is a separate method where you use the same periodising technique, but first you set $U$ to zero outside the Voronoi tile of the origin for $\Lambda^N$. In Fourier space, it is equivalent to sampling the Fourier transform on the dual lattice $\Lambda^*$ after having smoothed it out by convolving with a sinc filter. It's exactly like in sampling where you first filter the signal to avoid aliasing (except here you just use the brick wall filter). This has the consequence of typically creating "kinks" at the boundary of the Vornoi tiles but is easier to compute and does not require fancy resummation.

When the potential is long range, both methods will give rather different results. Depending on what you are interested in, one method may be more appropriate than another. An extreme example of this would be the 1D Coulomb potential for the interaction of two particles. In the first method, this will give periodic inverted parabolas, while in the second method, it will give a triangle wave. Notice that as expected, both agree at the minima, but the general structure is rather different.

The two methods are different, but since they both obey the same consistency condition in the infinite spatial period limit, they will give similar results in this limit. Since this is the limit you are interested in, because you usually want to model particles in space, for most practical purposes they coincide.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, it seems the way I was approaching this question was partially wrong!

Comment: Unfortunately I have limited knowledge of topology, so I can only grasp your reply. What really confuses me is the idea of "spatial periodicity going to infinity" on a torus. Regarding the MIC, I think I expressed myself in the wrong way: what I meant is that the minimum distance is obtained by minimizing over periodic pair, but it might not necessarely coincide with the cutoff. I realize that in MD MIC and, for example, Ewald are mutually exclusive, since the former implies some form of truncation.

Comment: Ok, after a quick literature search I now understand what "spatial periodicity goes to infinity" means.

Comment: I avoided mentioning topology and tori (on purpose). I only talked about periodicity. I'm just sending the spatial period to infinity, or in terms of the torus, the size of the torus is sent to infinity. Try thinking in 1D, the $T$-periodic functions approach all the functions as $T\to\infty$.

Comment: Also, I didn't talk about the cutoff. When I talk about Voronoi diagrams, it's because I'm considering minimising the distance between image points. Perhaps you should build intuition on parities potentials before treating the general $n$ point potential.

Comment: +1, great answer (and reminded me on our discussion we had when I asked a question about PBC; I've linked it under the question as a comment). Do you know a good (intro) reference (for a physicist) where one can read regarding all of this?

Comment: @LPZ yes, I mentioned cutoff/truncation simply because in the MD community it is usually associated to MIC. I.e. no MIC implies no truncation, while long-range treatment (e.g. Ewald) implies no MIC.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks! I would rather recommend looking into signal processing. It's easier to build intuition with image processing and the Shannon-Nyquist criterion than the method of images or Bloch states even if the underlying mathematical ideas are the same.

Comment: @LPZ Thanks, I see. And do you have a particular(pedagogical) reference for this in mind?

Comment: This is a very good answer to my original question, accepting it. Altough I might have asked myself the wrong question (see my second edit).